# Pandas column count mismatch after insert into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert a column of values from one dataframe to another. The total count of values of both the indiviual dataframes is `91744` but when I use

`df1.insert(loc=0, column='x1', value=ts)`

to insert the values of ts as the first column in df1, the value count after insertion turns out to be `84175` instead of actual `91744`. Please tell me what is wrong with this.

```
>>> df1.insert(loc=0, column='x1', value=ts)
>>> df1.x1.count()
84175
>>> ts.count()
0    91744
dtype: int64

>>> df1.describe()
                 x1            x2
count  84175.000000  91744.000000
mean       0.249044     11.744387
std        0.191239     13.294185
min        0.000000      1.000000
25%        0.108383      3.000000
50%        0.212760     12.000000
75%        0.311860     15.000000
max        1.000000    551.000000
```

Sample data is given below.

```
>>> df1.head()
   x2  x3  x4   x5                   x6  y
0  12   1  13  497  2017-11-07 09:30:38  0
1  25   1  17  259  2017-11-07 13:40:27  0
2  12   1  19  212  2017-11-07 18:05:24  0
3  13   1  13  477  2017-11-07 04:58:08  0
4  12   1   1  178  2017-11-09 09:00:09  0
>>> ts.head()
         x1
0  0.218561
1  0.269357
2  0.257698
3  0.238417
4  0.164645
```

My objective was to add the `x1` column from of `ts` dataframe as the first column of `df1` data frame.

Comment: What is `ts`? I am not able to reproduce the error. If it is some public dataset, can you provide it?

Comment: @AnkitSeth `ts` is the dataframe name that needs to be added to `df1` dataframe at column index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share some of your data frame i would recommend using merge instead of insert if you have a common column let's say `ID` for example your code will look like this:

```
mergedStuff = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id'], how='outer')
mergedStuff.head()
```

as simple as that

Comment: I have added a sample data in the main question above.